# А вы уже использовали тревогу c высоким приоритетом?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> Вы уже использовали тревогу c высоким приоритетом

Что-то не то с этим переводом?

Хотя начинают появляться мысли, что хитрая фраза (без "данного типа") нужна чтобы покрыть два пункта одновременно, вариант про "высокий приоритет" кажется каким-то неуместным. Предлагаю переформулировать.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Интересно, остальные тревоги более низкого приоритета?

Comment: Первые две тревоги действительно имеют высокий приоритет и попадают в "красную" очередь.

Comment: По опыту: на тревоги первых двух типов быстро реагируют всегда, в отличие от тревог остальных типов.

Comment: Эти две тревоги, помнится, в определённом количестве приводят к **немедленному удалению** (и, возможно, рассмотрению постфактум, не знаю). А те, что ниже, сначала идут на рассмотрение по очередям.

Comment: @D-side, но это же не мешает поменять перевод? Потому что в нём я не вижу отражение удаления, там только какой-то приоритет...

Comment: Это уже внутренняя кухня. Под термином обычно прячется сколько-то смысла. Можно придумать термин поабстрактнее. Вроде ["чёрная метка"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA)) :)

Comment: @D-side рассмотрение постфактум возможно, а ещё есть автобан от системы.

Comment: Пожалуй, надо всё-таки предлагать варианты. Поехали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы уже использовали тревогу о неприемлемости содержимого

Answer (score 1):

Оставить текущий вариант

> Вы уже использовали тревогу c высоким приоритетом